# Loop through object in async method

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I have an object that looks like this and stores some attributes:

[image: Object description]

Basically what I need is to loop through this object and get the `file` attribute of every key that I would later use in my code to generate multiple `Video-React` components. I tried to use `map()` function but the site will crash with the error:

```
Parsing error: Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function.
```

Even though the code sample that I am working with is inside an `async` function.

Here is my code:

```
            const response = await dataProvider(GET_MANY, 'vid', { ids: videoId })
            const file = response.data;
            file.map( source => {
                var videoPosition = 0;
                var sigkey = "sigkey";
                var formBody = new FormData();
                formBody.set('ver', "1.2");
                formBody.set('key', "key");
                formBody.set('video_id', file[videoPosition].file);
                formBody.set('user_id', "1234");
                formBody.set('format', "json");
                formBody.set('ip', "");
                formBody.set('tts', "0");
                formBody.set('nonce', Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000));

                var sign_fields = [formBody.get('video_id'), formBody.get('user_id'), formBody.get('ip'), formBody.get('tts'), formBody.get('ver'), formBody.get('key'), formBody.get('nonce')];
                var data = sign_fields.join(':');
                var signature = hmacsha256(data, sigkey);

                formBody.set('sig', signature);

                var formBodyStringified = new URLSearchParams(formBody).toString();

                const resJson = await fetch(Config.api.livebox, {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: formBodyStringified,
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
                    }
                }).then(res => res.json());
                const finalJsonUrl = 'https:' + resJson.hls;
                this.setState({ videoSource: finalJsonUrl });
                videoPosition++;
            });
```

Any suggestions how can I loop through the object?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: use `for of` instead of map.  Also your not using the return of map, so forEach would have been more logical.

Comment: Put all the code inside a function with a keyword `async`. and inside that `async` function you can use as much `await`

Comment: Your `await fetch` does *not* occur in an `async` function.

Comment: You need to include the `async` keyword in front of the callback passed to `response.map`, May I also suggest you put the map inside of a [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: @Keith Would you mind to post an example please? I am really not good with loops.

Comment: @AdamSulc  You basically just replace ->  `file.map(async source => { ...` with `for (const source of file) { ...`  This will then work as expected..   You could also use `Promise.all`, but do be aware that can come with some issues.  eg.  If the server you connecting to has limits on connections, and also doing 10 things at once due to thrashing is not always faster than doing 1 at a time.

Comment: @Keith I am still kind of wondering about forEach, since I want the state to have different value when the variable `videoPosition` is incremented at the end. Im not exactly sure what to use here, since loop are not my strong side

Comment: @AdamSulc Your using `videoPosition` to get the actual element, `file[videoPosition].file` would actually be the same as `source.file`..  This would also be the case if using `forEach` / `map` or the `for of`..

Comment: @Keith my idea of videoPosition was to increment it everytime I ran the loop, so that would change the value of state. Actually I need to create some sort of loop so that the sample I posted would happen twice.

Answer (score 2):

You should include an async tag even inside your map function:

```
file.map(async source => {
                var videoPosition = 0;
                var sigkey = "sigkey";
                var formBody = new FormData();
                formBody.set('ver', "1.2");
                formBody.set('key', "key");
                formBody.set('video_id', file[videoPosition].file);
                formBody.set('user_id', "1234");
                formBody.set('format', "json");
                formBody.set('ip', "");
                formBody.set('tts', "0");
                formBody.set('nonce', Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000));

                var sign_fields = [formBody.get('video_id'), formBody.get('user_id'), formBody.get('ip'), formBody.get('tts'), formBody.get('ver'), formBody.get('key'), formBody.get('nonce')];
                var data = sign_fields.join(':');
                var signature = hmacsha256(data, sigkey);

                formBody.set('sig', signature);

                var formBodyStringified = new URLSearchParams(formBody).toString();

                const resJson = await fetch(Config.api.livebox, {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: formBodyStringified,
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
                    }
                }).then(res => res.json());
```

Or you could use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```
const fetchList = file.map(source => {
                var videoPosition = 0;
                var sigkey = "sigkey";
                var formBody = new FormData();
                formBody.set('ver', "1.2");
                formBody.set('key', "key");
                formBody.set('video_id', file[videoPosition].file);
                formBody.set('user_id', "1234");
                formBody.set('format', "json");
                formBody.set('ip', "");
                formBody.set('tts', "0");
                formBody.set('nonce', Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000));

                var sign_fields = [formBody.get('video_id'), formBody.get('user_id'), formBody.get('ip'), formBody.get('tts'), formBody.get('ver'), formBody.get('key'), formBody.get('nonce')];
                var data = sign_fields.join(':');
                var signature = hmacsha256(data, sigkey);

                formBody.set('sig', signature);

                var formBodyStringified = new URLSearchParams(formBody).toString();

                const request = fetch(Config.api.livebox, {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: formBodyStringified,
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
                    }
                }).then(res => res.json());
return request;
 });

const resJsons = Promise.all(fetchList);
resJsons.forEach(resJson => {
                const finalJsonUrl = 'https:' + resJson.hls;
                this.setState({ videoSource: finalJsonUrl });
                ...
}
```

Comment: But do be aware this will execute all mapped elements in parallel.  And also loses error handling.

Comment: I suppose that's what the PO wanted judging from the code. If concurrency is a problem I would use a promise.all

Comment: I would have use `file.map( async (source) => {` 'cuz its more clear that we define a function

Comment: you'd have a better performance but like @Keith mentioned you'd have a problem if it's not managed well.

Comment: `promise.all` has no effect on concurrency.

Comment: Without some effort to limit concurrency, this could be fairly catastrophic.

Comment: promise.all will wait until all the fetchs in the map have finished. Whereas with async map In the scenario above we're updating the state with each result of fetch. Imagine promise B resolves before promise A . I don't think that's the result we want.

Answer (score 0):

You use `await` in this line:

```
const resJson = await fetch(Config.api.livebox)
```

but is not correct usage. because parent function is `map` callback function and it not async!.